# Error field wasn't correctly shown in django form

Tags: css, django, forms, validation, django-forms

I'm using Django form and trying to loop through the fields in my template.
I did it like this:

```
<form method = "post">
<span>
{% for error in form.errors %}
<p>{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</span>
{% for field in form %}
<span>
{{ field.label_tag }}
</span>
<div>
{{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% csrf_token %}
<button type = "submit">
</form>
```

However, when I did this, the error field shown in the template was displayed as "**all**".

Beside this everything's fine with this form.
I'm wondering what's going on.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the form like this(remember to add the CSS):

```
<form method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{field.errors.as_text|cut:'* '}}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type = "submit">
</form>
```